# How do I pass a JSON string to an AWS Lambda function from webpage Javascript without any API calls?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am attempting to send data entered into various fields of an HTML form on a webpage as a JSON string to AWS Lambda so that Lambda can enter that into a DynamoDB table. As this is for a class project, I've chosen to forego using a Gateway API, I just want to raw call the Lambda function from inside the webpage javascript and pass the JSON in as a parameter to the Lambda function. I have the webpage successfully calling the Lambda function, which I have hard coded to enter a predefined entry into the Dynamo table. I also have the web js making a JSON string from the form. My goal is to send the JSON string as a parameter to the Lambda function when I invoke it, but I'm not sure how I would go about that, as this is my first time working with AWS. I know I have to do something with the payload parameter, but I can't find a clear example as to what. I've made sure I have the proper credentials and SDK imports in the HTML. Below is my code:

Webpage JS:

```
var lambda = new AWS.Lambda();


function makeJSON(){
  var userID = "";
  var name = document.forms["characterForm"]["characterName"].value;
  //alert(name);
  //alert(typeof name);
  var race = document.forms["characterForm"]["race"].value;
  var playerClass = document.forms["characterForm"]["class"].value;
  var strength = document.forms["characterForm"]["strength"].value;
  var dexterity = document.forms["characterForm"]["dexterity"].value;
  var constitution = document.forms["characterForm"]["constitution"].value;
  var intelligence = document.forms["characterForm"]["intelligence"].value;
  var wisdom = document.forms["characterForm"]["wisdom"].value;
  var charisma = document.forms["characterForm"]["charisma"].value;


  //alert(name + race + playerClass + strength, dexterity, constitution, intelligence, wisdom, charisma);

  characterSheetObj = {userID: userID, name: name, race: race, class: playerClass, strength: strength, dexterity: dexterity, constitution: constitution, intelligence: intelligence, wisdom: wisdom, charisma: charisma}
  characterSheetJSON = JSON.stringify(characterSheetObj);

  var myParams = {
    FunctionName : 'addCharacterSheet',
    InvocationType : 'RequestResponse',
    LogType : 'None',
    //Payload : {"userID": userID, "name": name, "race": race, "class": playerClass, "strength": strength, "dexterity": dexterity, "constitution": constitution, "intelligence": intelligence, "wisdom": wisdom, "charisma" : charisma}
  }

  lambda.invoke(myParams, function(err, data){
      //if it errors, prompts an error message
      if (err) {
              alert("Error");
              prompt(err);
           }
           //otherwise puts up a message that it didnt error. the lambda function presently doesnt do anything
           //in the future the lambda function should produce a json file for the JavaScript here to do something with
           else {
              alert("Invoked Lambda function without erroring!");
           }
    });

}
```

Node Lambda Function:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const db = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: 'us-east-1'});
  exports.handler = async (event) => {
//  exports.handler = function(e, ctx, callback) { 

    let scanningParameters = {
        TableName : 'characterTable',
        Limit:100
    };

    db.scan(scanningParameters, function(err, data){
        if(err){
            callback(err,null);
        }else{
            callback(null,data);
        }
    });

    const params = {
        TableName : 'characterTable',
        Item: {
            name : 'Alan'
        }

        };

        const userID = '12345';
        params.Item.userID = userID;

      return await db.put(params).promise();
    };

//}
```

I think it has to do with events.body in the Node.js code, but again, I'm not very clear on it, and I can't suss very much out of Amazon's documentation. Any suggestions, tips, or resources to look at would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the payload as a JSON string:

```
var payload_obj = { name: "John", age: 30, city: "New York" };
var payload_json = JSON.stringify(payload_obj);

var myParams = {
    FunctionName: 'addCharacterSheet',
    InvocationType: 'RequestResponse',
    LogType: 'None',
    Payload: payload_json
  }

lambda.invoke(myParams, function(err, data){
      ...
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand your question correctly but your parameters passed to AWS Lambda is available at `event.arguments`